# Element unexpectedly taking up the full height of its container

Tags: html, css

Please visit "https://codepen.io/ColleenEMc/pen/QjOaxv" first.In the style sheet if we go to the "nav a" selector we can see display:block. Due to this the < a > element will occupy the full width of its container element, which is the < li > element. My question- if we hover over the < a > element(in the live demo) we can understand that the < a > element is occupying the full width and height of its container.(Since the whole background, having the dimensions of the < li > element, changes). Why is this happening? ie. *****Why is this (< a >) element occupying the full height of the container?*****
I went through other selectors too, but did not understand this behavior. Any help would be appreciated. If you need clarification on anything stated above, please ask. I want to know why this is happening.

Comment: You're required to post a [mcve] in your question

Comment: hey could you add your html and css scripts what you have tried so far, and what you are expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because your `<a>` is inheriting the `line-height` of it's parent (`<li>`), which is set to `50px`, the same as the `height` of the `<li>`. This makes each text line of the `<a>` be `50px` tall, and as it has only one line of text, it's overall height is `50px`.

In your code, it can be seen it here:

```css
nav li {
    width: 20%;
    border-right: 3px solid yellow;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 140%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -4px;
}
```

See how both `height` and `line-height` are set to `50px`. According to [MDN's page for `line-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height), this property is inherited by default.

If you want to disable it, just set `line-height` to `normal` or any other desired value on the `<a>` element, like:

```css
nav li > a {
    line-height: normal;
}
```

Comment: I understood it. Thanks!